# non-www to www redirect not working for articles in subdirectory installation of WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, web, subdirectory

I am helping out with a website that has a main/root website as well as a WordPress installation in a sub-directory.  The .htaccess file of the main site has rules to redirect non-www traffic to www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www\.site\.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, this has no effect on the WP site.  For instance:

- site.com would redirect to www.site.com
- site.com/some-content-belonging-to-root-site would redirect to www.site.com/some-content...
- site.com/wordpress does not redirect to www.site.com/wordpress

I added similar rules to the WordPress .htaccess, playing around to try to get the result I would expect, but the best I could come up with is this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www\.site\.com/wordpress/$1 [R=301,L]
```

...which successfully redirects site.com/wordpress to www.site.com/wordpress, but does not redirect site.com/wordpress/a-blog-post.

I feel like I must be missing something simple or obvious, but hours of experimentation and research have not yielded a thing except that .htaccess files in sub-directories are not advised (but I think this is unavoidable in this case).

I would be grateful for any suggestions on how to fix the rewrite condition or rule to successfully redirect the post links of the WP site.

Thanks!

EDIT / ADDITIONAL INFO: I modified the RewriteCond to better match the incoming URLs, thinking that this might help, but it has the same effect.  The base wordpress URL is rewritten, but article URLs are not:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}/wordpress/.* ^site\.com/wordpress/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www\.site\.com/wordpress/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I wouldn't think that it should matter, but just in case, I'll mention that the article URLs look like this:
site.com/wordpress/2014/05/16/article-slug

Comment: Check your permalink settings in Wordpress.

Comment: @anubhava - Thanks for the suggestion.  I hadn't thought of that, but it looks like those are already pointing to the www URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was not the rewrite conditions or rules, but the ***order*** in which they appeared in the .htaccess file.

I read a WP forum post in which someone suggested moving the rewrites to the top of the file for performance reasons.  I gave it a shot just to see what would happen and noticed that the URL for the articles was affected - not in a good way, but affected nonetheless.  I got something like this:

www.site.com/wordpressindex.php?/2014/05/16/article-slug

There were some rewrite rules to rewrite the base and redirect to the index given a nonexistent directory or file, which was what was building the garbled URL above.

In case it happens to help anyone else, I began with a .htaccess file that looked like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And ended up rearranging it to look like this, which now works to properly redirect all blog-related URLs to the www site:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /wordpress/

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}/wordpress ^site\.com/wordpress [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www\.site\.com/wordpress/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www\.site\.com/wordpress/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And clean your browser history to make sure.

Comment: Thanks, but that is what I noted that I already have implemented.  It works for the landing page, but not for the articles.

Comment: It's different, mark the dollar sign. Have you tried this?

Comment: I'm sorry - I totally missed that.  I gave it a try and it seems to work the same way with or without the $.

Comment: Your first example is also missing the dollar, that functions as variable.

Comment: I tried it exactly as you have it written with the dollar sign (with the correct domain), but it still doesn't catch the articles for some reason.  Based on your suggestion, I also gave this a try, but to the same effect:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}/wordpress ^site\.com/wordpress$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www\.site\.com/wordpress/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: I also tried it as you suggested with the first example.  So, like this:  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www\.site\.com$1 [R=301,L]
But this just redirects to the main site and doesn't seem to keep the /wordpress part of the URL.  I'm not sure if this is how it is supposed to work or whether it indicates that something else is going on.  It seems like,as written, it should keep any extra URL pieces handed to it.

Answer (score 0):

I also own a WordPress website and I was looking for www to non www redirect for my website : fasterthemes.com
The website is hosted in DigitalOcean and after struggling with several DAYS, I could figure out that all the solutions (.htaccess) codes available work fine if you've set the A record in your DNS settings properly. If it's not set then the redirection doesn't work !

So in my case,

1. I created one A record in my Digitalocean DNS like below :

i.stack.imgur.com/ie7f8.png

2. I added following code :

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond              %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

And now as you can see if you browse http://www.fasterthemes.com , it redirects you to fasterthemes.com. Earlier it was throwing an error.
I hope this helps.